# How to finish my medical training in the UK as an immigrant?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-kingdom, medicine

I was studying in medical university in Russia for two years and was in the top of my class, but circumstances led me to Wales, UK around 4 years ago (I'd soon be eligible to apply for a UK citizenship) and I want to continue studying medicine here.

Looking at the medical college requirements I understand that I need GSCEs and A-levels to be passed successfully. Frankly, it is overwhelming for me to cover 11 years of studying and I am afraid I can't do this.

I've tried to find alternative ways into school of medicine, but have no clear idea how to do it.
Few alternatives I found are:

- **Apprenticeship**. As far as I understand there is half accepted way to work and study and as a result to get some or most of GSCEs and A-levels covered. But I can't find whether these results are accepted by any uni whatsoever.
- **Gateway to medicine programs**. To my best knowledge, these are including few years of studying in college which guarantees you to be admitted into uni. But again can't find whether this is universal thing or every university has it's own rules. And also, do I have to pass GSCEs and A-leves or can I somehow transfer my foreign results.
- To become a nurse and somehow eventually to be accepted to the university (this isn't so clear whether this is possible).

One important thing is that I'd likely to start studying only when I'd get citizenship as I don't have enough funds to pay for the courses as international student.

Answer (score 5):

Admissions officers at all UK universities have a significant amount of information on educational systems around the globe and the mapping of a student's background to UK equivalents and are able to measure each applicants ability or academic level on admission.

Some examples of the information available might be:

- [UCAS Guide to World Qualifications 2015](https://www.ucas.com/sites/default/files/2015-international-qualifications.pdf)
- [UCAS Tariff Calculator 2022](https://www.ucas.com/ucas/tariff-calculator)
- [ECCTIS](https://www.ecctis.com/)

There are also many British citizens that have not obtained the necessary qualifications when leaving school but decide they want  to study in higher education later in life. (Often known as Mature Entry students). The UK education system has ways of enabling their entry to their desired course. One such route is a one year "Access to HE" course at a local college. These are usually accredited by a local university to certificate the late learner's academic level in a short time. There is a [factsheet available](https://www.medschools.ac.uk/media/2655/access-courses-infosheet.pdf) regarding Access courses for medicine specifically.

For applicants from overseas whose qualifications are of the right level but not done in English, then some form of English language qualification would be required. One such certification for this would be [IELTS](https://www.ielts.org/), but there are others that are equally recognised.

As mentioned in other answers, your best route to detailed information would be to consult an admissions officer at the University of your choice, or attend an "Open Day" event at a nearby university and speak to staff in person. Most universities have such recruitment events throughout the year.

I regularly speak to potential applicants in similar positions at open day events and will probably be handling their applications at some time during the year. This is not an unusual or abnormal situation, particularly considering the ebb and flow of world events over the recent past.

Addressing  the issue of an applicant who has already completed some of their course elsewhere (in the UK or overseas), some courses permit Accreditation of Prior Learning (APL or APEL or APCL) to allow someone to enter at a later stage of a course (such as only take the final year or skip the first year) by transferring credits, but this usually requires documentation such as a full curriculum specification and results transcript to be presented, often in notarised translation form.

Medicine is a special case; above I have addressed the general subject independent procedures. For medical schools, the best source of information is [The Medical Schools Council](https://www.medschools.ac.uk/studying-medicine/making-an-application/faqs). Unfortunately it is not possible to transfer credits from overseas into a UK medical school and therefore entry must be to the first year for an overseas applicant.

I hope I have covered all the necessary points both generally and specifically raised by your question.

---

<sub>Not part of a general answer, but specific to Cardiff:

There does not appear to be a full-time access to medicine course in Cardiff, but there is a part-time one. There are such courses offered in other cities. There are also online distance learning access to medicine courses available in the UK for home study. Cardiff does have a graduate entry scheme to medicine and this can be another route. It depends if you are willing to re-locate what option choices you have.</sub>

Comment: Re. "not possible to transfer credits from overseas" - It might be possible to use transfer credits towards a non-medical degree (e.g. biomedical science) and then enrol on a 'graduate entry'/'fast-track' medical degree. I have no idea whether this is a *good* idea - you would need to carefully investigate the financial and practical implications of doing so. Talking to some admissions tutors is definitely the way forward (and talk to several - you may find that some universities are able to offer more flexibility than others).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been on open day event in Cardiff Uni school of medicine and staff there didn't know how to help me. There were no specific advises on how to find a college which has "Access to HE" program compatible with their uni. It felt like the staff were less from admission but more like hands on doctors or professors, there were eager to speak about courses particulars but not admission process.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably find that most medical schools have a section that describes the entry requirements for overseas students. For example, my own university's medical school's entry criteria say:

> For all applicants, other qualifications are also considered for admission i.e. Scottish Highers, Irish Leaving Certificate, the International and European Baccalaureate and some national qualifications from students applying from other countries.  A number of qualifications, (including but not limited to BTECs, T-Levels and Access Courses) are not accepted.

https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/medicine/undergraduate/medicine-admissions/a100-mbchb-policy

I recommend you email the admissions tutors at the medical schools of your choice (or possible all medical schools in the country) to specifically discuss your situation.

Comment: That's good advice, to start as overseas student. But the problem is, that you needed to study in your home country in the school which has compatible courses. And I didn't. The second problem is that I am already in the UK. The 3rd problem is admission fees are significantly higher. So if there was a way to pass some exams as overseas student and transfer into being regular student that would be alright, but I don't know if it is doable.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't suggesting entry as an overseas student - you don't get a choice of overseas or home. Rather, if they have set out entry requirements for overseas students, those same requirements will apply to home students who have those qualifications. In any case, you should contact the admissions tutors. The worst that can happen is that they can tell you they don't accept your qualifications.